# Windowsphone - How to Make App can open Some Fileformats

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

i have a question 
i want to know how can i open downloaded file in my app (like when you download .PDF File in Internet Explorer it shows apps that can open .PDF files )
please help me snippet of codes !

Answer (score 0):

first you have to save your file in isolated storage and you need to use launcher this  code would help you:

```
private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

            // Access the bug query file.
            StorageFile yourfile = await local.GetFileAsync("Pradeep.pdf");

            // Launch the bug query file.
            Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(yourfile);
        }
```

this launcher is available in windows phone 8 only.

Comment: i think you are not completely understood my question !

Comment: how can i access file that Internet Explorer Downloaded?

Comment: its in internet explorer's sand box?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) :

> "*You can use file and URI associations in Windows Phone 8 to automatically launch your app when another app launches a specific file type or URI scheme. When launched, a deep link URI is used to send the file (a reference to the file) or URI to your app.*"

Basically you need to do following steps :

1. Register your application to be associated to a specific file type, for example `.pdf` file extension in this case. This step done by adding `<Extension>` in `WMAppManifest.xml`.
2. When your application get launched upon user opening a `.pdf` file, get file id from query string then get the physical file using `SharedStorageAccessManager` based on file id.
3. The rest is to handle opening the file in your application.

I found this very nice blog explaining the detail of every steps, accompanied with downloadable source code.

- [PART I: explaining background concept and creating application to launch associated file](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/a-lap-around-windows-phone-8-sdk-file-association-part-1/)
- [PART II: explaining details of step 1-3 above with sample application](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/a-lap-around-windows-phone-8-sdk-file-association-part-2/)